# SUSTITUIR EL VALOR DE UNA CADENA Y CAMBIARLO POR OTRO POSTGRES

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo la siguiente tabla.

[image: Mujeres]

como ven en el campo name, tengo un valor , y en el fullname es un valor diferente, requiero reemplazar el ultimo valor después del / es decir debe quedar de la siguiente manera

```
Bebés/Artículos/Coches y accesorios para bebés
```

He intentando con la function

```
select split_part(fullname, '/', name) from categories
```

pero no se como mas pueda hacerlo, ¿Alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacer lo siguiente, si lo que quieres es obtener el resultado:
**"Bebés/Artículos de Viaje/Coches y accesorios para bebés"**

Aqui tienes 2 maneras de hacer las cosas. quizá existan otras formas.

**La Primera:**
Como hay varios "/" en la columna fullname, una solución simple y rápida sería procesar la cadena después de la ultima "/" al revés, con [reverse()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), luego tomar la primera parte y hacerle reverse() una segunda vez, finalmente ya le haces un replace con la columna "name".

```
SELECT replace(fullname,reverse(split_part(reverse(fullname), '/', 1)),name)
```

**La Segunda:**
Hay otra manera, más versátil (y más costoso) , utilizando [substring()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) con una expresión regular:

```
SELECT replace(fullname,substring(fullname, '[^/]*$'),name)
```

Me comentas como te fue.

Comment: Esta perfecto, con ambas funciona pero se deben meter dentro de una funciona, muchas gracias!